# How to instantiate a Stream of String arrays by concatenating a single array with a Stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, covariance

Given a method with signature:

```
private String[] emitRecord(SomeType someType {...}
```

I would like to take `theRecordAsStream` defined as a stream of array of strings.

```
String[] someRecord = emitRecord(someType);
Stream<String[]> theRecordAsStream = Stream.of(someRecord);
```

and prepend it to and existing stream of arrays of string.

```
return Stream.concat(theRecordAsStream, eventsStream);
```

Unfortunately this is not possible as `Stream.of(someRecord)` returns a Stream which then triggers the following error on the concat.

```
Error:(118, 65) java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: java.lang.String[]
lower bounds: T,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String,T
```

What's the proper way to deal with this?

Comment: What is `eventsStream`

Comment: `theRecordAsStream` should be `Stream<String> theRecordAsStream`  and not `Stream<String[]> theRecordAsStream`

Comment: @c0der The entire point of the question is that OP wants a `Stream<String[]>` *("defined as a **stream of array of strings**")*, so telling OP that it *should be* a `Stream<String>` is not helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *explicitly* tell [`Stream.of(T t)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-) that you want a `Stream<String[]>`, i.e. you tell it that `T` is a `String[]`:

```
Stream<String[]> theRecordAsStream = Stream.<String[]>of(someRecord);
```

That way, the compiler cannot misinterpret it as call to [`Stream.of(T... values)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-), with `T` being a `String`, which is what you're currently experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the return value as follows:

```
String[] a = new String[]{"hello", "world"};
Stream<String[]> b = Stream.of(new String[][]{a});
```

Comment: You don't need the `new String[]` in the first line, i.e. `String[] a = {"hello", "world"};`

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what you want to do. If you would like to turn each element of the array into a string array, then what you need to do is as follows:

```
String[] array = {"hello", "world"};
Stream<String[]> stream = Arrays.stream(array).map(elem -> new String[]{elem});
```

And here is what it outputs:

```
stream.forEach(elem -> System.out.println(elem[0]));
hello
world
```

However, if you would like to create a stream which has only one element that is the result of the method, then you should do the following:

```
String[] array = {"hello", "world"};
Stream<String[]> stream = Stream.of(new String[][]{array});
```

And then in this case, in order to get the same result, you need to do the following:

```
stream.forEach(x -> Arrays.stream(x).forEach(System.out::println));
```